# Is it possible to keep the display of a web page indexed by a link in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, solid-js

I'm working on a multi-screen application designed in `solid-js`. One of my screens contains an iframe to a website of my own design. However, when I click on a link present in the content site, it returns me a web page but when I go to another screen of my application then I return to the page containing the iframe, the original site, namely the site defined in the iframe is displayed and not the page indexed via the url. So I'm wondering if it's possible to keep displaying an indexed webpage in the iframe from the browsing history. Here is the code of my iframe:

```
<iframe
      width="100%"
      height="1300"
      id="myiframe"
      src="https://gkwhelps.herokuapp.com"
    ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it is hard to understand but if I understood correctly you are trying to display the same page on both windows.

As a security measure JavaScript application can not access browser history so depending on history will not work but you can control window's href and iframe's src programmatically.

Here is a simple app which does so:

```js
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal, createEffect, on } from "solid-js";

function App() {
  let win: Window | null;

  const [link, setLink] = createSignal("https://solidjs.com");

  createEffect(
    on(link, () => {
      if (win) {
        console.log("updating window href");
        win.location.href = link();
      }
    })
  );

  const openWindow = () => {
    win = window.open(link(), "_blank", "location=yes,height=570,width=520");
  };

  const updateLink = () => {
    setLink("https://www.solidjs.com/guides/getting-started");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <iframe width="100%" height="300" id="myiframe" src={link()}></iframe>
      <button type="button" onClick={updateLink}>
        Update Link
      </button>{" "}
      <button type="button" onclick={openWindow}>
        Open Window
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

render(App, document.getElementById("app")!);
```